# cuda.is_available() returns True, but only torchvision cpu is installed

Tags: pytorch, gpu, torchvision

I need `torch` and `torchvision` with GPU support. Torch and torchaudio are installed as a GPU version, but torchvision is installed as a cpu version

```
> conda list
...
torch              2.0.0+cu117        pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio         2.0.1+cu117        pypi_0    pypi
torchvision        0.13.1       cpu_py310h378ed51_0
...
```

This Python script shows that CUDA is available

```
from torch import cuda
print(cuda.is_available())   # True
```

I have Windows11, CUDA 11.7 and Anaconda.
How can I install `torchvision` with GPU support?

Comment: Try removing those three libraries and reinstall them using `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia`

Comment: @Toyo Tried. This did not help. Torch was installed with cu117, but torchvision was installed as cpu only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me

1. Backup your Conda envs
2. Uninstall and reinstall Anaconda
3. Run `pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117`